# VB: Changing from console to forms makes the left function stop working

Tags: vb.net

I copied the exact code from my console version of the application and it won't work in forms [(shown here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrrHz.jpg). I think it is getting confused with another type of left function to do with the magnitude of a left property. The reason why I think this is because there is clearly a difference if you look at the left function's info [(shown here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWcCy.jpg).

Is it a different issue? How do I get it to stop bring up the error of "'Public Overloads Property Left As Integer' has no parameters and its return type cannot be indexed."

Comment: In WinForms, `Left` refers to `Me.Left`, which is the [`Form.Left` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control). You can still use the `Left()` function in WinForms by calling `Strings.Left()`. However, this function (along with all the other functions under the `Strings` module) only exist for backward compatibility for VB6 programmers back in the day. You should use the .NET standard methods instead. In this case [`String.Substring()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring).

Comment: The equivalent of `Strings.Left(ActualSearchWord, ActualSearchWord.Length - 8)` would be `ActualSearchWord.Substring(0, ActualSearchWord.Length - 8)`.